# T4 class feature blocks - method scope

Tags: templates, t4

When defining a method in a class feature block, what effect does the scope have? I'm speaking in the context of standard templates, not preprocessed templates. Can the scope be left out? If a private scope is declared, does it affect accessibility from includes or other areas of a template?

```
<#+

private void Method()
{
//...
}

#>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the template (includes and all) is just generating a single overarching class, so that is the scope. In your example, "Method" is a private method on that class, so can be reached from any other method in the template.

In other words, in most cases, it is largely meaningless for design-time (standard) templates.
If it is left out, then its just as with a regular class, it defaults to private.